# Why do I get an error "Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'user' available as request attribute" in this case?

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, spring-validator

Why do I get this error? Before connecting the validation and adding forms of the 
form: label / input - everything worked for me

```
 @RequestMapping(method = POST, value = "/reg")
    public String registration(@ModelAttribute("userReg") @Valid User user, BindingResult bindingResult,
                               HttpSession session) {
        if(bindingResult.hasErrors()) return "redirect:/reg";
        if (userDAO.findByLogin(user.getLogin()) == null) {
            userDAO.persist(user);
            session.setAttribute("login", user.getLogin());
            return "welcomepage";
        }
        return "Registration";
    }
```

Exceptions:

```
 org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /Registration.jsp at line 18

    15: <form:form action="/reg" method="post" modelAttribute="user">
    16:         <table>
    17:             <tr>
    18:                 <td><form:label path="login">Login:</form:label></td>
    19:                 <td> <form:input path="login"/> </td>
    20:                 <td> <form:errors path="login"/></td>
    21:             </tr>

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'user' available as request attribute
```

Continuing the form from the error:

```
 ...<p>
            <tr>
                <td> <form:label  path="password">Password:</form:label></td>
                <td> <form:input  path="password"/> </td>
                <td> <form:errors path="password"/></td>
            </tr>
        <p>
    <input type="submit" value="Registration">
</form:form>
```

Answer (score 1):

This error happens because you don't pass the object 'user' to Model in your controller.
Returning ModelAndView is a option but you can put the object in the Model object and return your page address.

```
@GetMapping("/user") 
public View retrieveUser(ModelMap model, HttpServletRequest request) {
  model.addAttribute("user", userService.getUser());
  String contextPath = request.getContextPath();

return new RedirectView(contextPath); }
```

Comment: Also a good solution.
It's strange that my friend was didn't need to add an attribute to the model.
It was enough for him to accept Binding Result and make a redirect

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the page did not have the required attribute. And the error crashed because the name field was not found in the "user" that was not filled.
To fix the error i added object ModelAndView() with "user" atribute.

```
@RequestMapping(method = GET, value = "/reg")
public ModelAndView registration() {
    return new ModelAndView("Registration","user",new User());
}
```